# use ng-model in <ul> list generated by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add ng-model to each `<li>` in my `<ul>`, so I can show the `<li>` label that I am clicking in my list.

```
<ul ng-repeat="prop in props" class={{prop.selected}} ng-click="setSelected(prop )" ng-model="selectedpropName">
    <li ng-cloak >{{prop.label}}</li>
</ul>
My Selected Property: {{selectedpropName}}
```

I know that this is not correct way and angular way to do it. What is the right way?
Please help

Comment: I think you want to repeat the li element (not the ul element), don't you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```js
function test($scope)
{
  $scope.setSelected = function(prop) {
      $scope.selectedprop = prop; 
  };

  $scope.props = [{label: "Aaaaaa"},{label: "Bbbbbb"},{label: "Cccccc"}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>li.selected {text-decoration: underline;}</style>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="test">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="prop in props" ng-click="setSelected(prop)" ng-class="{selected: prop == selectedprop}" ng-cloak="">{{prop.label}}</li>
  </ul>

  My Selected Property:  {{selectedprop.label}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ng-model binds to the `prop`, not to it's `label` field, so you probably use something like this:

```
My Selected Property:  {{selectedpropName.label}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** Just use `ng-click="modelYouWantToSet = valueYouWantItToBe`.

As an alternative to @pln's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117600/4826740) you could can set it in the `ng-click` event like this: `ng-click="selectedPropName = prop"` and get rid of the need for these extra functions.

So your code would become:
    
        {{prop.label}}

```
My Selected Property: {{selectedpropName}}
```

Additionally if you have extra logic you need to boil in you can still set it to a function like this `ng-click="selectedPropName = myCoolFunc(prop)` and then in `myCoolFunc` you can do what you need, and then return the `prop`.

For example lets say I wanted to *only* set this property when the user does a mouse click *or* presses enter on the element:

Template:

```
<ul ng-repeat="prop in props" 
    class={{prop.selected}} 
    ng-click="selectedPropName = myCoolFunc(selectedPropName, prop)">
    <li ng-cloak >{{prop.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.myCoolFunc = function(originalProp, newProp) {
      return (e && (e.type === 'click' || e.keyCode === 13) ? 
              newProp : 
              originalProp;
  };
```